# How to post to a users Facebook Pages or Tabs

Tags: facebook, api

We are looking at the Facebook C# API and have a question on how to go about posting to a persons specific pages, and/ore to a specific tab on their profile.

in the documentation, they show how to post to ("me/feed") ... but I can't find any documentation on how we would post to a specifci page owned by that user or a tab on their facebook profile. We've tried /me/, but that didn't work

could someone share how we go about posting to a specifci page or tab?
thanks

Comment: Erm, `me` == *you*. Replace that with *someone else*

Answer (score -2):

hello michel  user after authenticates Your application with manage_pages permission
use
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/accounts?access_token=xxxx
this will return pages information with page tokens
use the following to post messages 
https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed?access_token=xxxx&message=xx 
if u want Any further information let me know